# Question regarding the proof of Theorem 6.1.2 Tom Dieck

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory, higher-homotopy-groups

I'd like to understand the proof of the exact sequence of the pair in homotopy. I'm reffering to the one I found here: [https://www.maths.ed.ac.uk/~v1ranick/papers/diecktop.pdf](https://www.maths.ed.ac.uk/%7Ev1ranick/papers/diecktop.pdf) (p.123)

The implication I don't understand is $\text{Ker}(j_{*}) \subseteq \text{Im}(i_*)$.

I do understand the logic behind the proof but I don't get the following :

$1.$ Why $i_*[k \star u] = k \star w?$ Shouldn't always be true that if two out of four edges of the square are the costant path then the other two "edges" (representing a path) are homotopic? I don't get how $i_*$ plays a special role here.

$2.$ Related to $1$. I'd like to find an explicit homotopy of the square in order to achieve $k\star u \simeq k \star w$, as stated in the following:

[image]

Any help,hint or reference would be appreciated.